# Create a text file in windows application

Tags: c#, .net

I want to open a text file and write some data to the file.
Here is my code:

```
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("D:\\Yourfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
        writer.Write("Hello");
        writer.Close();
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\\Yourfile.txt");
```

This code works fine.But here first the file is getting saved.
I want a text file to open along with the data and let the user save the text file.
Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean you want the text file to open along with the data?

Comment: @neoistheone I think the OP wants to have notepad pop up with the text entered in it but not saved yet.

Comment: Sorry for bad english.I mean write some text inside the text file.

Comment: ok,you just want to open a new notepad with the text from Yourfile.txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this will solve your problem

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        

            Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (notepads.Length == 0)
            {
                Process.Start(@"notepad.exe");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
               // return;
            if (notepads[0] != null)
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, "Hello");
            }              

        }
```

Comment: @Priyanka: is this useful to you?

Comment: With this line it only asking the user to save it for the first time.Once the file is created on the D:  drive it is directly opening it.I want a new unsaved text file to open every time.And write some data into it programatically.

Comment: @Priyanka:you can open an instance of Notepad, get the handle for the window, then write the text directly into there. You will need to use Windows User APIs to do this.

Comment: @priyanka: i worked on your problem and found a solution to solve, please try this,if it is useful please mark my answer as a solution

Comment: while executing the code, did any new instance of notepad opened up?

Comment: No notepad file did not open up.

Comment: i successfully tested in windows XP and in windows 7, try  to create a new application and add 1 button and try again,this will definitly work, before that close all already opened notepad window and increase the thread.sleep() value

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding you correctly, you would like your program to open Notepad and put some text in it. Then, the user will decide if the file will be saved or not.

If that is the case, you can use the `Process` class to launch notepad. Once you do that, you [can fire a series of keyboard events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx) (which mimic keys) so that you will have text.

That being said, what I think could be a cleaner solution would be to open a seperate Form with a text area/text box so that the user can read through. Then, have a button called `Save` which essentially does what you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the user to provide text for the file, then build a Windows Form with a single text box. Let the user type whatever they want, and when you're done, do this:

```
File.WriteAllText(pathToFile, textBox.Text);
```